# jqGrid does not display search button(icon)

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have this following code for displaying data , it works fine , 
but it does not show search icon, what things i lost in my code?

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ 
 url:'post2.php',
 datatype:"json",
 colNames:['id','lastname','fname'],
 colModel:[ 
 {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true, width:90}, 
 {name:'fname',index:'fname', width:90}, 
 {name:'lastname',index:'lastname', width:100}
  ], 
 rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30],
 pager: '#pager2',
 height:'100%',
 sortname: 'id',
 viewrecords: true,
 sortorder: "asc", caption:"example1" }); 

 jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{search:true, searchtext:"Search"});
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

thanks oleg

i found the problem , jqgrid 3.7 dose not display search icon with jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom

and with jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom its word fine

Comment: In general jqgrid 3.7.x works fine with jQuery UI 1.8.2. I use this combination for example. One more general remark. You should better write a comment to my answer instead of writing your own answer. In case of writing of comment I'll receive a notification and can read your answer. Now I read your answer randomly. But I am glad that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you posted has no errors (I don't count the switching between column names 'lastname' and 'fname' as an error). The default value `searchicon:"ui-icon-search"` are used for the search icon. You should verify that you correct include jQuery UI (CSS with coresponding images) in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I realize the OP found an answer, but there is another situation to consider that affected me and might help someone else.

I had a typo in my `div id` reference for the pager.  I had accidentally exluded the 'r' in pager.  Interestingly, my `jqgrid's` pager was both intact and working.  Only the "search" icon was missing (which is the same behavior the OP mentions).

**Wrong** :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#page2',{search:true, searchtext:"Search"});
```

**Correct** :

```
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{search:true, searchtext:"Search"});
```

Make sure your referenced id actually matches the `id` from the html tag.